# Injecting app level setting into project level setting in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to setup a cron job for celery beat, but I don't want to put the schedule information in the project level `settings.py` , is there a way to inject app level settings into project level setting such that it will play nicely with the entire project?

`celery_config.py` in `celery_task app`

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'name_of_job': {
        'task': 'task.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'args': (16, 0)
},
}
```

`settings.py`

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djcelery',
    'celery_task'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option would be to specify the location of the configuration file via the Celery command line argument **--config**

The second option is to do something similar to what I do when I need to have settings that are environment/deployment specific:

Include a section at the bottom of your settings.py file that imports the settings from your app wrapped in a try statement to avoid breaking the site if the app settings file isn't available.

Example:

```
/* bottom of settings.py */
try:
    from celery_app.celery_config import *
except:
    print 'Did not find celery_config'
```

This will try to load the settings file from your app but will avoid any errors if the app isn't present in the project folder.

**IMPORTANT**: Use only unique celery related configuration variables as this will override any previously defined settings in your settings.py file